# Data not being sent over channels

Tags: concurrency, go, channel, goroutine

I have this code here

https://gist.github.com/ChasingLogic/8324442

I'm trying to learn network programming with Golang this is my first attempt at concurrency and the goal is the equivalent of a stripped down irc server where a message is sent and echoed to all connected clients.

For some reason my code never gets past sending the data into the channels. If I put an error check in it just infinitely spits out EOF.

Comment: What is `n, err := conn.Read(buf[0:])` supposed to do if buf is empty? It seems you are never really populating your channels.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not really clear on what you mean. I thought that conn.Read would block until data was sent? Also not sure what populating my channels means. I searched the godoc and effective go about it and came up with nothing.

Comment: @ChasingLogic he means that "var buf []byte" leads to buf being empty slice. Try "buf := make([]byte, 1024)" instead.

Comment: @Kluyg I feel really dumb now, thanks. I did make that change but it still won't send across the channels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. Empty buf in handleClient
2. Deadlock between sender and receiver

The first is easy - just use "buf := make([]byte, 1024)" instead of "var buf []byte".

The second one in more detail.

In handleClient you have

```
fmt.Println(string(buf[0:n]))
mesg <- buf[0:n]
fmt.Println(mesg)
ind <- n 
fmt.Println(ind)
```

So you send the message first and then - message length. But on receiver side you have:

```
n := <-ind
fmt.Println("N recieved")
buf := <-mesg
fmt.Println("Channels recieved")
```

So you expect message length before the message itself. So there is a deadlock: the sender is waiting for someone to receive the message before sending the length but receiver is waiting to receive message length before receiving the message.

Just change handleClient to have the opposite order and it will work:

```
fmt.Println(string(buf[0:n]))
ind <- n
mesg <- buf[0:n]
fmt.Println(mesg)
fmt.Println(ind)
```

Comment: Feel real dumb. Thank you so much.

Comment: @ChasingLogic No problem, that's how we all learn :) Btw, you don't need message length channel at all, the slice structure already have length inside it. And pay attention to concurrency issues - you have a resource (buffer) shared across many concurrent goroutines (one send and a lot of receive). "mesg <- buf[0:n]" sends not the copy but only the slice (which is basically a pointer to an underlying array + start pos + end pos). So there will be concurrency issues when many clients will simultaneously send a lot of messages.

Comment: oh, and also only one client will receive the sent message, since all the clients are blocked in "buf := <-mesg" and only one (random one) will be unblocked when there is a message in the channel, he will read the message from the channel and the channel will be empty after that, so no other clients will unblock / receive the message.

Comment: Yeah I fixed this by creating a client struct (so I can save a username for them as well) and then everytime they connect I add them to a package level array called clients and I am running the sendmessage go routine only once instead of for every connection. Now when the message gets sent on the channel send message unblocks then loops through the Clients slice writing to each client.